# How to custom background and border dropdown-list of select tag with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a [select tag]. Ex:

```
<select>
    <option>Option1</option>
    <option>Option2</option>
    <option>Option3</option>
</select>
```

And have been customizing it for aqua 0.05.

And this is working properly in IE 11 and chrome.

But when choosing the list for selection, it is a rectangle with the background is white and the border is 2px thick black. It does not fit the whole.

[Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vo57H.jpg)

I want to customize it for 0.05 aqua background, what are the solutions with CSS?

I will access my web in IE11 or EDGE.

Thank guys !

Comment: looks like this person has alot of examples   https://codepen.io/ericrasch/pen/zjDBx

Comment: Hi Bryan Dellinger ! It is still the default: (

Comment: What is 0.05 aqua background?

Comment: I think a working example would help. Is your page online accessible?

Comment: Hi, zer00ne ! Is is rgba(255,255,255,0.05)

Comment: Hi , Kloker ! My web cannot access on internet. This is source demo. https://1drv.ms/u/s!At82TnZCq3zrgaseBZsFXAORdpSoNg